# removing decimals in R

Tags: regex, r

I have some column values as follows:

```
HG.1T.1
HG.1T
HG.1T.2
HG.1T.3
HG.1T.5
HG.1T.11
```

I would like to remove everything after the second decimal and tried this

```
 result<-sapply(strsplit(rownames(trial),"\\."),function(x),paste0,head(x,-1),collapse="."))
```

and ended up with

```
HG.1T
HG
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
```

It works fine except that for the second value since there is only one decimal value, it removes that. I want this to work only in instances of two decimals and let the one decimal values remain as such. How do I do that? It should be

```
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
HG.1T
```

Comment: Don't use rownames and things will be much easier. It looks like you rbinded or merged some stuff. Before doing that, `DF$rn = rownames(df); rownames(DF) <- NULL` will put your rownames in a column, where they'll be much less hassle.

Comment: I think you could use `gsub("^.*?\\d*\\.?\\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\\d*\\.?\\d+", "", x, perl=T)` - it is exactly a solution to remove any decimals/integers but not the first. For your exact case, `\\d*\\.?` can be replaced with just a `\\.`. Or `gsub("^(.*?\\d*\\.?\\d+)|\\d*\\.?\\d+", "\\1", x, perl=T)`. But you already accepted a work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` by matching a `.` followed by one or more numeric characters (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string and replace with `''`.

```
sub("\\.\\d+$", "", df1$Col)
#[1] "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T"
```

---

Or we capture one more non-dot characters (`[^.]+`) followed by a `.` followed by one or more non-dot characters (`[^.]+`) as a group and replace with the backreference (`\\1`).

```
sub("(^[^.]+[.][^.]+).*", "\\1", df1$Col)
#[1] "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col = c("HG.1T.1", "HG.1T", "HG.1T.2", "HG.1T.3", 
"HG.1T.5", "HG.1T.11")), .Names = "Col", class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: No, this still removes everything after the first decimal for the second value in the column.

Comment: @Paul Updated the post

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use regex,

```
sapply(df$Col1, function(i) paste(strsplit(i,"\\.")[[1]][1:2],collapse = "."))
# HG.1T.1    HG.1T  HG.1T.2  HG.1T.3  HG.1T.5 HG.1T.11 
# "HG.1T"  "HG.1T"  "HG.1T"  "HG.1T"  "HG.1T"  "HG.1T"
```

Answer (score 3):

With regexpr:

```
regmatches(df1$Col,regexpr("[A-Z]{2}[.]{1}[0-9]{+}[T]",df1$Col))

[1] "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T" "HG.1T"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove everything after the second decimal:

```
sub("^(([^.]+\\.){2}).*", "\\1", "HG.1T.11")
```

To replicate what the OP indicates in his output, the following will work:

```
sub("^(([^.]+|\\.){3}).*", "\\1", "HG.1T.11")
```

Comment: ?? it should give you `HG.`

Comment: @AvinashRaj See my new and improved expressions.